# Missing $ inserted with tikzpicture

Tags: pdftex, tikz-external, debugging

Forgive me if I breach ettiquite here, it's been a while...

A couple of years ago I wrote two papers as part of my PhD research and submitted them to a journal...they were each about 20 pages long.  The editor suggested I combine them into a single paper that was no more than 25 pages.  I couldn't be bothered, and have let them sit.

Now I'm having a go at putting them together....I've cut and pasted bits together into a new document.  And I am encountering an error with practically every use of tikzpicture, despite the fact that the code is cut and paste from a working document.

I attempted to build a minimal example, but when I do, they work just fine...this tells me my error is probably somewhere else, but I have no idea how to track it down.

As an example, here is one of the figure blocks

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{extikzpicture}[runs=2]
        \begin{axis}[
                height=8cm,
                width=6cm,
                xmin=0,
                xmax=260,
                legend style={draw=none},
                legend style={at={(0.95,0.325)}},
                xlabel = Simulation Day,
                ylabel = $\alpha$ Value,
                width=0.75\textwidth,
                y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
    }]
            \addplot+[black, mark=o,line join=round, mark repeat=50] table[col sep=comma, y=-100, x=Day]{AlphaPlusResourcesIncreasing.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize $\rho = -100$}}
            \addplot+[black, mark=x,line join=round, mark repeat=50] table[col sep=comma, y=-50, x=Day]{AlphaPlusResourcesIncreasing.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize $\rho = -50$}}
            \addplot+[black, mark=|,line join=round, mark repeat=50] table[col sep=comma, y=0, x=Day]{AlphaPlusResourcesIncreasing.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize $\rho=\infty$}}
            \addplot+[black, mark=square,line join=round, mark repeat=50] table[col sep=comma, y=50, x=Day]{AlphaPlusResourcesIncreasing.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize $\rho = 50$}}
            \addplot+[black, mark=triangle,line join=round, mark repeat=50] table[col sep=comma, y=100, x=Day]{AlphaPlusResourcesIncreasing.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize $\rho = 100$}}
        \end{axis}
    \end{extikzpicture}
    \caption{$\mathbf{\alpha}$ Values for Selected Values of $\rho$}
    \label{AlphaByRho_Increasing}
  \end{figure}
```

Everything preceding this renders fine...and then I get an error, indicated as being on the line

```
\end{extikzpicture}
```

Actually I get three errors...twice I get

> ! Missing $
>   inserted

And then I get an error telling me that the externalized file wasn't found...not surprising since it wasn't generated.

I've been over these and over these and can't see where I've got unbalanced $'s...so I guess I'm asking if anybody has any tips on how to track that down.

Additional info:

I've been trying to build an MWE that generates the error and I cannot!  Perhaps this will illustrate my frustration.  I began by taking my document (its just under 2300 lines) and commenting out everything but the preamble and the first figure.  The first figure has the advantage that the data is contained in the tikz code, not in an external file.  I still get the errors about missing $.

But, and here's the frustrating part, I then created a new file and cut/pasted only the uncommented portions of the document....so just the preamble and the first figure...and that file builds fine.

So here's my attempted MWE:

```
\documentclass{singlecol-new}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\usepackage[external]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    external/prefix=\jobname-,
    external/safety=0mm,
    external/input source on error=false,
    }

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\tcbEXTERNALIZE
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{extikzpicture}[runs=2]{fig1}
        \begin{axis}[
                xlabel=Model Size,
                ylabel=Avg Project Score,
                width=0.75\textwidth]
            \addplot+[red,
                                error bars/.cd,
                      y dir=both, 
                                y explicit,
                                ]
                    coordinates {
                    (3, 0.608)  +- (0.0495, 0.0495)
                    (4, 0.621)  +- (0.0406, 0.0406)
                    (5, 0.589)  +- (0.0410, 0.0410)
                    (6, 0.569)  +- (0.0381, 0.0381)
                    (7, 0.549)  +- (0.0354, 0.0354)
                    (8, 0.542)  +- (0.0341, 0.0341)
                    (9, 0.558)  +- (0.0331, 0.0331)
                    };
                \addlegendentry{{\small Model-Specific Avg Score}}
                \addplot[black] coordinates {
                    (3, 0.577)
                    (4, 0.577)
                    (5, 0.577)
                    (6, 0.577)
                    (7, 0.577)
                    (8, 0.577)
                    (9, 0.577)
                    };
                    \addlegendentry{{\small Aggregate Avg Score}}
        \end{axis}
    \end{extikzpicture}
    \caption{Average Score (95\% Confidence Interval) versus Model Size}
    \label{ScoreSize}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I attempt to build my project that is nothing more than the above code surrounded by a bunch of commented out text, I get errors in the console about missing $'s and an output document that looks like this:

[image]

I do not understand how this can be.

The whole thing is too big to paste in here...but I'm quite certain that everything is commented out except what is in the MWE above.  I'm not trying to be difficult, I just have no idea how to proceed and no clue how to clearly demonstrate what's going on since I can't duplicate it....

Comment: Could you please enlighten us what kind of environment `extikzpicture` is? In more detail, please provide a complete MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass`, loads all the necessary packages, and ends with `\end{document}`. Also, provide some dummy data. Otherwise one cannot try things out.

Comment: To debug this, just comment all lines out which contain a `$`. Assuming that this runs through, just restore these lines one by one. It might also be that your data file has something inappropriate in it.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure AlphaByRho isn't the issue.  I get this same set of errors for every instance of an extikzpicture...even very simple ones.  I did a find for $'s and walked through every instance in the 350 lines preceding the first figure and they all line up....very frustrated.  If I try to build an MWE with just a figure, it builds just fine...so clearly something is happening in the preceding text and only getting caught in the figure, but I can't find what.

Comment: extikzpicture is a figure generated by the tikz package and "externalized" so that it generates a separate file with the figure....that way later, when you submit to the publication, your latex can simply include the figure and you don't have to send all the data, etc to rebuild them

Comment: Well, you would greatly benefit from telling us what this exttikzpicture is. The only other post containing it that I could find was a question by you. Quite conceivable that there is something in your preamble that does not get seen by the externalizer...

Comment: Let me try how I see things: you have a self-written (?) environment that is at least not known to most of us, an incomplete code, and in addition you are able to compile all the pictures. So the simplest solution is, I think, that you just produce pdfs of all these plots and include them via `\includegraphics`. Quite possible that the journal will insist on this anyway. For all these reasons, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: As marmot says, if you want help then you need to provide a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). You have only given us code snippets, which include an unknown `extikzpicture` environment, so we have no way to reproduce your error and hence no possible way of helping you.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is in your unknown `extikzpicture` environment as your code seems to work if you replace this with a `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: Close voters - this question is only 4 hours old, you should give the OP a chance to respond after a nights sleep.

Comment: (i)  `extikzpicture` seems to be defied in the `pgfplots` library `external`; (ii) without seeing minimal working example is not possible to help; (iii) i wonder if externalization of this picture is really necessary (in short document).

Comment: I've added a bit to the OP as well as my attempt at an MWE, but as the description says it's not very illuminating.  Externalization is necessary as the final submission to the journal has to be LaTeX that simply includes graphics...so I need to build external files for each of the figures that I can include with the submission.  I did this 5 or 6 times when I was finishing up my degree and never had this issue.  This is the same code just pasted together into a new document so I don't understand.I could see if I had left out a $ someplace but my attempts at an MWE seem to have ruled that out

Comment: @jerH If you are certain that everything is commented out except what is in the MWE above, then make a copy and remove everything which is commented out. Does it still reproduce the problem?

Comment: Also try to clear all your external images to force them being recreated (after making a copy - just to be safe)

Comment: @samcarter Did that...I now have two tabs sitting next to each other in TeXnicCenter with identical text.  When I click "build current file" on one I get no errors and the chart I expect.  When I do it on the other, I get missing $ errors...

Comment: @jerH Make a copy of the original file that produces the error and save it under a different name. Does it compile?

Comment: I also ran a diff on the two files and got nothing...

Comment: @samcarter Wow....that makes no sense.  I copied the non-working MWE to a new filename and that file builds fine....

Comment: @jerH OK, I think the problem is caused by your old auxiliary files. Try to delete them and compile the original code again

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the help!  I still don't really know what happened.  I had tried deleting the .aux files early on and it didn't make a difference.  Ultimately I created a new folder, a new TeXnicCenter project, and then just cut and pasted the code into that and it worked...well, the $ errors went away!  Still have two other issues but I'll post about those separately!

Comment: @AndrewSwann I generally agree, but want to draw your attention to the fact that the OP has just asked [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449898/121799) (in which he, quite surprisingly, was able to provide a preamble). So I do not think that the issue is that the OP had no time to respond. Rather, I am not sure if he is willing to.

Comment: @marmot My apologies if these are poorly put questions...I use latex about once every other year and this stuff with tikz is at the very edge of what I know how to do.

Comment: The problem is that people here really want to help you, but they can't because you are holding crucial input back. Having said that, let me say that I will be happy to reopen the question if you provide a valid preamble. like the one in your newer question, but with an official document class or a link where one can find the one you are using.

Comment: A this point I don't think its necessary...as I said above, though I don't understand why it worked, creating a new project and pasting the same code into it resolved these errors.  I would understand it to be an issue with .aux files except that I had already tried deleting those and rebuilding and made no progress.  But I made a new folder, a new TexNicCenter project in that folder, pasted the code into a new .tex document and poof, no more missing $ errors....I appreciate the effort that you guys put into helping people like me.

Comment: From the second image you've added it looks like the problem is related to an underscore in a file name that ends in `_run.tex` somewhere near the text `and Effects of Parameters`

Comment: If it fails in your real project, try to remove the auxiliary files (maybe they are corrupted).