# Cryptic tikz error - 'pgfpmth@float@max'

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

I have a tikz chart that won't build.  When I check the log file I find

> Package PGF Math error: Could not parse input 'pgfpmth@float@max' as a
>   floating point number, sorry.  The unreadable part was near
>   'pgfpmth@float@max'...

Here's the stripped down document for the figure

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{singlecol-new}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\usepackage[external]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    external/prefix=\jobname-,
    external/safety=0mm,
    external/input source on error=false,
    }

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\tcbEXTERNALIZE
\tikzexternalize



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{extikzpicture}{fig12}
        \pgfplotsset{%
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize},
        mycolorbar/.style={%
    colorbar horizontal,
    every colorbar/.append style={%
      x tick label style={%
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    \begin{groupplot}[
      height=4.5cm,
      width=4.5cm,
      group style={%
        group size=2 by 2,
                vertical sep=1.75cm,
        group name=fig12_plots,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        ylabels at=edge left
      },
      xlabel = {\footnotesize $\rho$},
      ylabel = {\footnotesize $\gamma$},
      %colorbar to name=Fig6Colorbar,
      colormap/blackwhite,
      y tick label style={%
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd
      },
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
      }
    ]
      \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize $\mathbf{\alpha_{+}}$ Begins Low}, z buffer=sort]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusIncreasingSurface.txt};
      \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize $\mathbf{\alpha_{+}}$ Begins High}, z buffer=sort]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusDecreasingSurface.txt};
      \nextgroupplot[mycolorbar, title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {PlusIncreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
      \nextgroupplot[mycolorbar, title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {PlusDecreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{extikzpicture}
  \caption{+Resources Reactive}
  \label{PlusReactive}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of the first data file, PlusIncreasingSurface.txt...they all look the same.

```
-10 0.01    9.250480808
-10 0.02    9.6164802
-10 0.03    9.4312822
-10 0.04    9.6188972
-10 0.05    9.471719
-10 0.06    9.2064946
-10 0.07    9.5651233
-10 0.08    9.4111867
-10 0.09    9.2320786
-10 0.10    9.2916034
-10 0.11    9.2072908
-10 0.12    9.332304
-10 0.13    9.4726249
-10 0.14    9.0733666
-10 0.15    9.2326564
-10 0.16    9.4104037
-10 0.17    9.531018
-10 0.18    9.6183388
-10 0.19    9.4074017
-10 0.20    8.9777363

-9  0.01    9.5901199
-9  0.02    9.3113474
-9  0.03    9.5205515
-9  0.04    9.4915627
-9  0.05    9.5789371
-9  0.06    9.3264085
-9  0.07    9.3801551
-9  0.08    9.2439982
-9  0.09    9.2470587
-9  0.10    9.3844433
-9  0.11    9.4101485
-9  0.12    9.5325451
-9  0.13    9.3166398
-9  0.14    9.5100066
-9  0.15    9.597391
-9  0.16    9.7489977
-9  0.17    9.2409027
-9  0.18    9.4081398
-9  0.19    9.580957
-9  0.20    9.3584576

-8  0.01    9.440366667
-8  0.02    9.3823564
-8  0.03    9.4903508
-8  0.04    9.5797672
-8  0.05    9.504578
-8  0.06    9.4142316
-8  0.07    9.6077734
-8  0.08    9.2817125
-8  0.09    9.5374557
-8  0.10    9.5580515
-8  0.11    9.7800136
-8  0.12    9.3772913
-8  0.13    9.3858585
-8  0.14    9.312432
-8  0.15    9.6032563
-8  0.16    9.4309408
-8  0.17    9.3687788
-8  0.18    9.5874027
-8  0.19    9.3183033
-8  0.20    9.301691

-7  0.01    9.6412536
-7  0.02    9.6273875
-7  0.03    9.7791091
-7  0.04    9.5599082
-7  0.05    9.2506278
-7  0.06    9.5120827
-7  0.07    9.4112214
-7  0.08    9.6139986
-7  0.09    9.4821886
-7  0.10    9.300827
-7  0.11    9.1732066
-7  0.12    9.4705888
-7  0.13    9.339989
-7  0.14    9.4852938
-7  0.15    9.7046371
-7  0.16    9.5110451
-7  0.17    9.5199757
-7  0.18    9.3755527
-7  0.19    9.4695994
-7  0.20    9.2933976

-6  0.01    9.4825631
-6  0.02    9.5425606
-6  0.03    9.3943889
-6  0.04    9.51751
-6  0.05    9.4154376
-6  0.06    9.4221127
-6  0.07    9.3403381
-6  0.08    9.3671098
-6  0.09    9.5945031
-6  0.10    9.6299679
-6  0.11    9.6116188
-6  0.12    9.3866165
-6  0.13    9.5213986
-6  0.14    9.2163047
-6  0.15    9.2600665
-6  0.16    9.2622377
-6  0.17    9.4293238
-6  0.18    9.474828
-6  0.19    9.4025582
-6  0.20    9.2687335

-5  0.01    9.3075683
-5  0.02    9.5287933
-5  0.03    9.3314617
-5  0.04    9.3697441
-5  0.05    9.2571777
-5  0.06    9.1880495
-5  0.07    9.5728407
-5  0.08    9.4006724
-5  0.09    9.5419555
-5  0.10    9.6682072
-5  0.11    9.394096
-5  0.12    9.0681965
-5  0.13    9.4017628
-5  0.14    9.2654993
-5  0.15    9.7554778
-5  0.16    8.9378944
-5  0.17    9.4342826
-5  0.18    9.255783
-5  0.19    9.1457342
-5  0.20    9.6373517

-4  0.01    9.4272485
-4  0.02    9.3569011
-4  0.03    9.3306385
-4  0.04    9.4908658
-4  0.05    9.4945985
-4  0.06    9.721668
-4  0.07    9.1076201
-4  0.08    9.4235444
-4  0.09    9.323132
-4  0.10    9.1971587
-4  0.11    9.5244951
-4  0.12    9.4592242
-4  0.13    9.4302187
-4  0.14    9.5437729
-4  0.15    9.538834949
-4  0.16    9.6795672
-4  0.17    9.4202734
-4  0.18    9.4509011
-4  0.19    9.3884072
-4  0.20    9.4132171

-3  0.01    9.5903105
-3  0.02    9.4117244
-3  0.03    9.3435099
-3  0.04    9.1989658
-3  0.05    9.3535967
-3  0.06    9.7867706
-3  0.07    9.3010534
-3  0.08    9.696961
-3  0.09    9.7652667
-3  0.10    9.6557783
-3  0.11    9.2509849
-3  0.12    9.4117925
-3  0.13    9.4595522
-3  0.14    9.6462419
-3  0.15    9.3907806
-3  0.16    9.4496049
-3  0.17    9.2171864
-3  0.18    9.3279925
-3  0.19    9.3832304
-3  0.20    9.5995443

-2  0.01    9.2802086
-2  0.02    9.266919
-2  0.03    9.1020916
-2  0.04    9.3102462
-2  0.05    9.3125325
-2  0.06    9.3720216
-2  0.07    9.3480875
-2  0.08    9.4807713
-2  0.09    9.7115706
-2  0.10    9.1754025
-2  0.11    9.6157867
-2  0.12    9.3850295
-2  0.13    9.2928526
-2  0.14    9.5268218
-2  0.15    9.2143366
-2  0.16    9.2560688
-2  0.17    9.4103511
-2  0.18    9.3217216
-2  0.19    9.5576217
-2  0.20    9.3620007

-1  0.01    9.4195118
-1  0.02    9.3431196
-1  0.03    9.1716917
-1  0.04    9.249538
-1  0.05    9.5950269
-1  0.06    9.4387348
-1  0.07    9.317707
-1  0.08    9.2083589
-1  0.09    9.5564109
-1  0.10    9.6025908
-1  0.11    9.7416701
-1  0.12    9.3035484
-1  0.13    9.4440138
-1  0.14    9.239332
-1  0.15    9.5282863
-1  0.16    9.4565429
-1  0.17    9.3358358
-1  0.18    9.4686243
-1  0.19    9.2476188
-1  0.20    9.2652357

0   0.01    9.5177522
0   0.02    9.4955568
0   0.03    9.2452598
0   0.04    9.0044349
0   0.05    9.2128682
0   0.06    9.2761498
0   0.07    9.2804913
0   0.08    9.3644198
0   0.09    9.4683515
0   0.10    9.2782927
0   0.11    9.2019294
0   0.12    9.7708413
0   0.13    9.3967028
0   0.14    9.2461917
0   0.15    9.3961118
0   0.16    9.5027796
0   0.17    9.5557349
0   0.18    9.3524396
0   0.19    9.2766739
0   0.20    9.0402404

1   0.01    9.3675941
1   0.02    9.5894049
1   0.03    9.050195455
1   0.04    9.3910875
1   0.05    9.0656323
1   0.06    9.1909184
1   0.07    9.2625527
1   0.08    9.3141393
1   0.09    9.5451076
1   0.10    9.1409439
1   0.11    9.1958265
1   0.12    9.5771733
1   0.13    9.3512711
1   0.14    9.4797647
1   0.15    9.4235439
1   0.16    9.3166154
1   0.17    9.4439237
1   0.18    9.3032665
1   0.19    9.4352584
1   0.20    8.9533932

2   0.01    9.3378089
2   0.02    9.515881
2   0.03    9.4450212
2   0.04    9.0095342
2   0.05    8.9783226
2   0.06    9.1666688
2   0.07    8.9049715
2   0.08    9.02264
2   0.09    9.1822582
2   0.10    9.2243216
2   0.11    9.3243799
2   0.12    9.4958822
2   0.13    9.2676996
2   0.14    8.932524
2   0.15    9.1687365
2   0.16    9.4162637
2   0.17    9.404654
2   0.18    9.344894
2   0.19    9.207297
2   0.20    9.0976664

3   0.01    9.5547438
3   0.02    9.463432
3   0.03    9.362089
3   0.04    9.4277218
3   0.05    9.2871938
3   0.06    9.1740819
3   0.07    9.0836825
3   0.08    9.4582932
3   0.09    8.99578
3   0.10    9.2111376
3   0.11    9.2729318
3   0.12    9.453922
3   0.13    9.2543584
3   0.14    9.3016575
3   0.15    8.959711
3   0.16    9.1642362
3   0.17    9.2122756
3   0.18    9.2052112
3   0.19    9.04073899
3   0.20    9.0475794

4   0.01    9.5903808
4   0.02    9.455843
4   0.03    9.4096613
4   0.04    9.3079914
4   0.05    9.6573634
4   0.06    9.3130989
4   0.07    9.0053174
4   0.08    9.4326377
4   0.09    9.1518232
4   0.10    9.2186498
4   0.11    9.3852724
4   0.12    9.381018
4   0.13    9.3512661
4   0.14    9.2734071
4   0.15    9.1286275
4   0.16    9.4690485
4   0.17    9.2582539
4   0.18    9.2708007
4   0.19    9.4588722
4   0.20    9.1050072

5   0.01    9.6706733
5   0.02    9.609477
5   0.03    9.5820841
5   0.04    9.3118871
5   0.05    9.0772721
5   0.06    9.056031
5   0.07    9.1745943
5   0.08    9.4139687
5   0.09    9.0817984
5   0.10    9.2178712
5   0.11    9.2398826
5   0.12    9.1825002
5   0.13    9.3639786
5   0.14    9.3381733
5   0.15    9.2326801
5   0.16    9.3803901
5   0.17    9.5228893
5   0.18    9.1691031
5   0.19    9.3775811
5   0.20    8.6699048

6   0.01    9.2354573
6   0.02    9.0710977
6   0.03    9.5794278
6   0.04    9.2161762
6   0.05    9.2961627
6   0.06    9.1924401
6   0.07    9.1454286
6   0.08    9.107345
6   0.09    9.1543621
6   0.10    9.3482784
6   0.11    9.644093
6   0.12    9.4998313
6   0.13    9.135289
6   0.14    9.071957
6   0.15    9.3570004
6   0.16    9.289596
6   0.17    9.3195163
6   0.18    9.5465944
6   0.19    9.4806573
6   0.20    8.9455427

7   0.01    9.601885
7   0.02    9.5623668
7   0.03    9.0278867
7   0.04    9.178856
7   0.05    9.4213336
7   0.06    9.289623
7   0.07    8.9465261
7   0.08    9.2709998
7   0.09    9.1322994
7   0.10    9.0460165
7   0.11    9.4724456
7   0.12    9.2292254
7   0.13    9.3170275
7   0.14    9.2506082
7   0.15    9.3544453
7   0.16    9.517243
7   0.17    9.4005841
7   0.18    9.2097599
7   0.19    9.1778804
7   0.20    8.8452948

8   0.01    9.3510262
8   0.02    9.4032409
8   0.03    9.0078369
8   0.04    9.0423234
8   0.05    9.5016245
8   0.06    9.4802264
8   0.07    9.3327828
8   0.08    9.054107
8   0.09    9.6068057
8   0.10    9.278689
8   0.11    9.5061997
8   0.12    9.2423039
8   0.13    9.0584217
8   0.14    8.9858656
8   0.15    9.3624097
8   0.16    9.4533844
8   0.17    9.4145469
8   0.18    9.2406855
8   0.19    9.474923
8   0.20    9.0623607

9   0.01    9.599864
9   0.02    9.4108812
9   0.03    9.2940561
9   0.04    9.090941
9   0.05    9.171887677
9   0.06    9.4922294
9   0.07    9.3225937
9   0.08    9.4927527
9   0.09    9.3225344
9   0.10    9.293855
9   0.11    9.5083226
9   0.12    9.9241456
9   0.13    9.1433406
9   0.14    9.2734356
9   0.15    8.9532278
9   0.16    9.047349
9   0.17    9.3955855
9   0.18    9.544821
9   0.19    9.0364454
9   0.20    9.131244

10  0.01    9.5743725
10  0.02    9.2949842
10  0.03    9.1054477
10  0.04    9.4570045
10  0.05    9.1817375
10  0.06    9.0321801
10  0.07    8.9876928
10  0.08    9.1545575
10  0.09    9.5077292
10  0.10    9.0884441
10  0.11    9.4635717
10  0.12    9.2956041
10  0.13    9.0821114
10  0.14    9.5289542
10  0.15    9.1904206
10  0.16    9.2395552
10  0.17    9.6099095
10  0.18    9.4872645
10  0.19    9.145132
10  0.20    8.9107495
```

I have no idea how to proceed with this...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84775/discussion-on-question-by-jerh-cryptic-tikz-error-pgfpmthfloatmax).